# Have there been any significant new critical frameworks since the 2000s?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches

I'm trying to mentally form a somewhat comprehensive list of types of criticisms/approaches to Biblical studies and what the lay of the land looks like as of 2023--as well as a rough timeline for when each type of criticism made its appearance. Is there anything that seems obviously missing/incorrect in the following list?

- Textual criticism [a.k.a. "Lower" criticism] (1500s-1600s)
- Source criticism (late 1700s-1800s)
- Form criticism (early 1900s)
- Tradition-historical criticism (mid-1900s)
- Redaction criticism (mid-1900s)
- Canonical criticism (1970s-1980s)
- Rhetorical criticism (1980s-1990s)
- Structural criticism (1990s)
- Narrative criticism (1990s)
- Linguistic approach (1990s-2000s)
- Social-scientific approach (2000s)

Also, is it a correct way to understand the historical-critical method and the historical-contextual method as being the "umbrella disciplines" that would encompass all the various types and criticisms mentioned above?

Comment: A more comprehensive list is available from [Wikipedia - Biblical Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_criticism). Also related [Wikipedia - Historical-Grammatical Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical-grammatical_method).

Comment: What do you mean by "current"? Hermeneutics uses all of them.

Comment: @curiousdannii - my apologies if I wasn't clear enough; I meant both: Are there are any of the major/key approaches that I missed--including the "latest and greatest" that might have emerged since the early 2000s?

Comment: Matthew Longhorn posts regularly on b-greek about publication of new linguistic frameworks. https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/search.php?search_id=active_topics